# CSS nav display

Tags: css, navigation, styling, nav

I'm a relative newbie and I'm having trouble following the css for my nav. I need to do 2 things:
1) run my sub menu inline
2) hide my sub-sub nav, and show it inline as well.

Here is the test site: http://gbetza.mydomain.com/webservice2/test/Basso56/test/home.html

Here is the CSS: http://gbetza.mydomain.com/webservice2/test/Basso56/test/css/style%20-%20Copy.css

I'm having trouble understanding which class I need to adjust as well as how.

Thank you

Comment: PLease include the relevant and only the relevant code rto reproduce the problem... also see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Don't just link to you site. The code there may change as you attempt to solve the problem

Comment: Further more use a tool like Firebug (https://getfirebug.com/) for Firefox or Developer Tools in Chrome (https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/) to get an understanding of what CSS classes are affecting which elements.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I thought the links were a better way to get the code/problem viewed as I only have limited characters here and the nav css is quite long.

Answer (score 0):

Copy + Paste from a similar answer of mine.

I have created a really simple implementation of this. It is barebones so that you can get a real easy look at the basic concept.

In the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/WS3QQ/2/

HTML - Note how the sub-menus are nested

```
<div id="nav">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Top Menu</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Sub-Menu</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub-Menu</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub-Menu</a></li>
        </ul>       
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Top Menu</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Top Menu</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Top Menu</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS - note how you can easily target the sub-menus (#nav li li). By default the sub-menu li is hidden (display:none). When the li is hovered over, the sub menu li is shown (display:block).

```
#nav ul { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
#nav li { float: left; } 
#nav li li { clear: left; display: none; }
#nav li:hover li { display: block; }
#nav li:hover a { background: #111; }
#nav li a { background: #333; padding: 10px; display: block; color: #FFF; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none; }
#nav li a:hover { background: #3914AF; }
```

Comment: Thanks, that works, but it doesn't place the sub nav items in a horizontal row. Can you help me there?